# YASnippet -- How to create a right-click context menu -- popup-menu

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I'm looking for a way to duplicate the YASnippet easy menu-bar entries for the snippets in my library (that appear in the menu automatically based upon whatever mode is being used), and incorporate them into my own custom menu.  The entry of `yas--minor-mode-menu` does not work.  The code I'm looking for will essentially be the same one that works with the regular easy menu bar customization:

```
(easy-menu-define my-custom-menu LaTeX-mode-map "My own custom menu"
'("My Stuff"
["YASnippet" yas--minor-menu-mode t]
("Sub Menu"
["My subentry" my-obscure-function t])))
```

The right-click context menu in the screenshot below uses pretty much the same thing:

```
(define-key map [mymenu]   (cons "MyMenu" (make-sparse-keymap "hello world")))
(define-key map [mymenu 01]  (cons "latexmk" 'run-latexmk))
(define-key map [mymenu 02]  (cons "jump-to-pdf" 'TeX-view))
```

I'm reluctant to give up and simply define each snippet and then create a menu-entry for each definition:

```
(defun bold ()
(interactive) 
(yas--expand-or-visit-from-menu (quote latex-mode) "bold"))
```

[image: screenshot1]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/YASnippet.png))</sub>

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defvar lawlist-context-menu-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap "Context Menu")))
    (define-key map [help-for-help] (cons "Help" 'help-for-help))
    (define-key map [seperator-two] '(menu-item "--"))
    (define-key map [my-menu] (cons "LAWLIST" (make-sparse-keymap "My Menu")))
    (define-key map [my-menu 01] (cons "Next Line" 'next-line))
    (define-key map [my-menu 02] (cons "Previous Line" 'previous-line))
    (define-key map [seperator-one] '(menu-item "--"))
  map) "Keymap for the LAWLIST context menu.")

(defun lawlist-popup-context-menu  (event &optional prefix)
  "Popup a context menu."
  (interactive "@e \nP")
    (define-key lawlist-context-menu-map [lawlist-major-mode-menu]
      `(menu-item ,(symbol-name major-mode)
        ,(mouse-menu-major-mode-map) :visible t))
    (define-key lawlist-context-menu-map (vector major-mode)
      `(menu-item ,(concat "YAS " (symbol-name major-mode))
        ,(gethash major-mode yas--menu-table)
          :visible (yas--show-menu-p ',major-mode)))
    (popup-menu lawlist-context-menu-map event prefix))

(global-set-key [mouse-3] 'lawlist-popup-context-menu)
```

---

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/context-menu.png))</sub>